# Is there a way to make the ::before pseudo element appear at the beginning of the line instead of at the end of the previous line?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a little triangle indicator for highlighted text:

I added it with the ::before pseudo-element:

```css
.highlight {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.highlight::before {
    content: "";
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #47484a;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5px;
    left: -3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In lacinia ligula eget tempus mollis. Maecenas <span class="highlight">maximus</span> interdum libero vel varius. Pellentesque quis varius augue. Phasellus facilisis, turpis et commodo posuere, leo enim egestas magna, id luctus sapien neque eget ligula. Pellentesque a imperdiet libero. In nec leo tempor, egestas massa quis, iaculis leo. Donec mattis mauris placerat congue egestas. Aliquam vehicula dictum scelerisque.
</p>
```

But if the highlight happens to be on the beginning of a line (which happens if you change the screen size), [the indicator appears at the end of the previous line instead of the beginning of the current one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf6Xh.png).

Is there a way to tell the browser to not do this? It doesn't happen in Firefox so I'm assuming it's an issue with Chrome

Comment: Does making "highlight" an inline-block work?

Comment: @DannyNiu it will, but if there ever was a "highlight" that goes across more than one line, it will cause it to sit there as an ugly "block."

Comment: @CBroe. I see. But it'll work well with single-word cases. Multi-word cases can have its dedicated rule I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a gradient to create that shape

```css
.highlight {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,#47484a 5px,yellow 0);
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In lacinia ligula eget tempus mollis. Maecenas <span class="highlight">maximus</span> interdum libero vel varius. Pellentesque quis varius augue. Phasellus facilisis, turpis et commodo posuere, leo enim egestas magna, id luctus sapien neque eget ligula. Pellentesque a <span class="highlight">imperdiet libero. In nec leo tempor, egestas massa quis, iaculis leo.</span> Donec mattis mauris placerat congue egestas. Aliquam vehicula dictum scelerisque.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `highlight` class an `inline-block` appears to work. But that'll break some minor details such as word-breaking.

```css
.highlight {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.highlight::before {
    content: "";
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #47484a;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.5px;
    left: -3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In lacinia ligula eget tempus mollis. Maecenas <span class="highlight">maximus</span> interdum libero vel varius. Pellentesque quis varius augue. Phasellus facilisis, turpis et commodo posuere, leo enim egestas magna, id luctus sapien neque eget ligula. Pellentesque a imperdiet libero. In nec leo tempor, egestas massa quis, iaculis leo. Donec mattis mauris placerat congue egestas. Aliquam vehicula dictum scelerisque.
</p>
```